# Getting a web site address using a keyword in python script

Tags: python, search

I have a large number of company names in an Excel sheet. I need to write a Python script to extract the:

1. company website name,
2. email id and
3. phone number

Can you please provide guidance?

Comment: This website is generally oriented towards more specific questions. This is a very broad question. Could you at least provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get help, you need to show what your input looks like, what is your expected output, and what you have done so far.

Comment: I am sorry but Its too hard to help you without more information. Please let us know what your inputs look like and what your expected outputs would be. Also try to refine and focus on the question you have, the most specific you are the more we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you get your Excel data into Python:

http://www.python-excel.org/

Example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Try this to return URL's based on your keywords by leveraging Google:

```
from google import search
for url in search('put your search query here', stop=15):
    print(url)
```

you can limit the number of urls by using `stop =` any number you want.

Alternately, to capture all of the data you need, you might try using something like `cURL`, `lxml`, or other "scraping" tools and scraping a site such as **Crunchbase** which typically catalogs that information in a structured format. You can programmatically pass in the keywords from your Excel file into a prepared Crunchbase URL. This also might work with a website like yellowpages.com or whitepages.com.